# How to keep repeated values in a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say I got something like `((1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3))`. As you can see, 2 is repeated across all of tuples in the tuple. I want something to return `(2)`.

The real data set I'm working on is:

```py
(
  (2, 3, 5, 7, 9),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
)
```

And I'm excepting it to return `(2, 3, 5, 7)`.

I have already tried the following, but it returns an empty tuple for some reason.

```py
a = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3))
print(tuple(filter(lambda x: all(x in i for i in a), a)))
```

There are three things that are important to me.

1. No usage of mutable data & statements
2. As less `for` as possible, instead `map` or `filter`
3. It should all be fit in one line, so I can turn it to a lambda function or so...

So basically, I want to do this functionally.

Comment: "It should all be fit in one line, so I can turn it to a lambda function or so ..." why does that matter? Why *must* you use a lambda expression to define your function? You can just use a regular functiond efinition statement. Using a lambda expression doesn't make it any more functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking a group of tuples and returning a single different tuple. So `filter` is not really what you want. If you are thinking about functional programming, this really seems like a problem for [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

That might look like:

```
from functools import reduce

t = ((2, 3, 5, 7, 9), (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

reduce(lambda res, curr: tuple(n for n in res if n in curr), t)
# (2, 3, 5, 7)
```

Here you just create a single tuple `res` on each iteration, which contains values seen by all lists.

Comment: plus one :) I was going with `reduce(set.intersection, t[1:], set(t[0]))` but your answer feels cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @AndrejKesely, sets do seem like a natural answer — the requirement for no mutable data structures gave me pause.

Comment: @Mark yes, not to mention this is pretty inefficient

Comment: I mean, you *can* use a `frozenset` but it is a silly requirement. If oyu want to practice functional programming, you can just *not use mutator methods* instead of avoiding any type that is mutable in Python

Answer (score 2):

Here, using `functools.reduce`, you can do something like:

```
reduce(frozenset.intersection, map(frozenset, data))
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems like the nicest way to work around the non-mutable requirement without sacrificing efficiency.

Comment: How many times this method will create frozenset ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi `len(data)` times. I would never do this this way without the immutable restriction

Comment: I think its more than len(data) because first you are creating it in map and then while using reduce it always create one new forzenset for each reduce step ?

Comment: sure, then `2*len(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*set.intersection(*map(set, t)),)
```

p.s. Looks like I have to add some words to avoid labeling the answer as *low quality*. But the idea seems quite obvious: create sets from tuples and get their intersection.

**Update**

It seems that we could do without `reduce` or `map` by creating a set or frozen set once and providing *iterables* to its `intersection` method:

```
frozenset(t[0]).intersection(*t[1:])
```

Comment: `(*<whatever>,)` should just be `tuple(whatever)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In most cases, this is a matter of taste or corporate rules. In this case, this may be reasonable in order to avoid missing a comma at the end. But I think that your remark will save the situation. Therefore, leaving things as it is will be quite informative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Counter`

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
a = ((2, 3, 5, 7, 9), (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
print([ele[0] for ele in Counter(chain(*a)).items() if ele[1]==len(a)])
```

Comment: Running this prints `[(2, 9), (3, 9), (5, 9), (7, 9)]`. That doesn't seem like the result the OP wants.

Comment: This is for giving clarity how many time these are repeating, just in case OP want keys only then simple `ele[0]` will work.

Comment: Okay, but it produces the incorrect result on some edges cases, like when the element that appears the most often doesn't appear in every tuple. For example: `a = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 6))` prints `[(2, 3)]` but `2` is not in every tuple. Similarly, if tuples have duplicate values this can return the wrong thing.

Comment: @Mark Yes you are right, I have done the required modification.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:
Given:

```
from functools import reduce
a = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3))
def combo(a, b)
    return a&b
reduce(combo, [set(x) for x in a])
```

Yields {2}